# Debugging backbone apps using developer tools

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js, marionette

I am a newbie to Backbone web applications.  I have good experience in Angularjs.  In angularjs, we can easily debug controller functions or get service objects by using `angular.element($0).scope()` or `angular.element($0).injector().get('serviceName')`.

Is there something similar available in backbone that lets me inspect the current state of the application and trigger any functions if required?

Comment: The majority of Backbone Apps very close to MVC, but View also in share Controller responsibilities, so in most cases its composite of Models and Views, so Model keeps data, that may be counted as state, view render this data. So you can dump any model current state via `model.on('change', this.dump, this)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/backbone-debugger/bhljhndlimiafopmmhjlgfpnnchjjbhd?hl=en) which is able to show you all views, models, collections and routers and its data.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone doesn't provide any inspection tools out of the box.

Using the chrome dev tools debugger (adding break points) might be your best shot.
I find the debugger extremely useful for inspecting and debugging backbone applications.